# How can I fix this kind of CSS margin issue?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML like this,

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-item">
        // my stuff...
    </div>  
    <div class="gallery-item">
        // my stuff...
    </div>  
    <div class="gallery-item">
        // my stuff...
    </div>  
    <div class="gallery-item">
        // my stuff...
    </div>  
    <div class="gallery-item">
        // my stuff...
    </div>  
    <div class="gallery-item">
        // my stuff...
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need to do using this HTML is, within `gallery` it should display 3 `gallery-item` divs as a table row. In this case 6 `gallery-item` should display in 2 rows.

My problem is when using margin for `gallery-item` divs. I need to remove right margin of the 3rd div in each row and 3 div should be center within `gallery`.

This is my CSS

```
.gallery {
    width: 560; 
    background: red;
}

.gallery-item {
    background: gray;
    width: 172px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RYe57/) for better understanding.

Hope someone will help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for pointed it. But it is not my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following might work:

```
.gallery {
    width: 544px; 
    background: red;
}

.gallery-item {
    background: gray;
    width: 172px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.gallery-item:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background: yellow;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/s3x38/

I used the `nth-child` selector to pick out every 3rd `.gallery-item` and apply the CSS rule to set the right margin to 0.

I also adjusted the with of `.gallery` to account for the reduced width of the parent container.

**Reference**

You can learn more about the `nth-child` selector at:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: Yes, thats the one I expect. can I get some explanation about how `nth-child` selector work with this case.